# How does one can determine the runtime of the following algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, runtime, complexity-theory, code-complexity

```
for n in range (1, n):
   for j in range(1, n+1):
       k = 1
       while k <= j:
           sumfunc()
           k *= 42
```

(Python code, meaning from 1 to n)
How would one determine the numbers of calls of `somefunc()` and thus the runtime of this algorithm, if `somefunc()` would be the influencing part?

Other problems of this type I just converted to some summation and solved it, but this one is a bit trickier.

I noticed that until `n = 41` everything is linear but after that `log42(n)` gets involved, but I don‘t know how to use this fact.

Comment: Say, running time of `somefunc()` is `O(M)`, then the overall running time is `O(n^2 * (M log 42 (n)))`

Answer (score 1):

You technically just need to get a timestamp before and after the code execution and then subtract the before from the after timestamp to get the execution time of your code snippet:

```
import time

t0 = time.time()

for n in range (1, n):
   for j in range(1, n+1):
      k = 1
      while k <= j:
         sumfunc()
         k *= 42

t1 = time.time()

total = t1-t0
```

Comment: Sorry it is n, not 300